# Problem with mapping in NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, mapping

I've the following class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string AccountNumber { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string CustomerType { get; set; }
    public virtual int TerritoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual SalesTerritory Territory { get; protected set; }
}
```

And it is being mapped using Fluent NHibernate as follows:

```
    public class CustomerMapper : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    private const string schema = "Sales";
    public CustomerMapper()
    {
        SchemaIs(schema);
        Id(x => x.CustomerID);
        Map(x => x.CustomerType).WithLengthOf(1).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.TerritoryID).Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.AccountNumber).ReadOnly()
            .Update(false)
            .Insert(false)
            .Generated(Generated.Insert);

        References<SalesTerritory>(x => x.Territory).TheColumnNameIs(ReflectionHelper.GetProperty<Customer>(x => x.TerritoryID).Name).LazyLoad().Update(false).Insert(false);
    }
}
```

The Update and Insert methods are just extension methods that set the ***update*** and ***insert*** attributes of a property in the generated mapping file.

This is how the resulting mapping file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-lazy="true" assembly="Model" namespace="Model" schema="Sales">
    <class name="Customer" table="`Customer`" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
        <id name="CustomerID" column="CustomerID" type="Int32">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="AccountNumber" column="AccountNumber" insert="false" update="false" generated="insert" length="100" type="String">
            <column name="AccountNumber" />
        </property>
        <property name="TerritoryID" column="TerritoryID" not-null="true" type="Int32">
            <column name="TerritoryID" />
        </property>
        <property name="CustomerType" column="CustomerType" not-null="true" length="1" type="String">
            <column name="CustomerType" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one lazy="proxy" update="false" insert="false" name="Territory" column="TerritoryID" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My problem is that when a save a new customer instance into the database, the customer instance have its Territory property as null.
How can I make this property to contain the correct value after saving into the database?
I am looking at something like the ***generated*** attribute for properties which retrieve the correct value after the session is flushed.
Or is there something wrong with my Customer class? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:** The database that I'm using for this model is AdventureWorks (SQL2005), tables Sales.Customer and Sales.SalesTerritory.

Answer (score 2):

A more sensible mapping would be like:

```
public class CustomerMapper : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    private const string schema = "Sales";
    public CustomerMapper()
    {
        SchemaIs(schema);
        Id(x => x.CustomerID);
        Map(x => x.CustomerType).WithLengthOf(1).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.AccountNumber).ReadOnly()
           .Generated(Generated.Insert);
        References(x => x.Territory).LazyLoad();
    }
}
```

Some points:

- This counts in being a mapped SalesTerritory class.
- TerritoryID is not necessary.
- If you use Insert(false) and Update(false) those properties won't be saved to the database. ReadOnly() does both Insert(false) and Update(false).
- CostumerType could perfectly be an enum.

This is more or less the idea (air code).

Comment: I'm going to go with your suggestion, initially I was doing it that, seems to be the right one. Oh, and thanks for the tip about ReadOnly, wasn't aware of that +1.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapping is quite strange ...
What is the relation of the territoryId property with the Territory property ?
In the many-to-one mapping , where you map the Territory property, don't you have to specify the type of the Territory ? (SalesTerritory).
You're mapping 2 properties to the same column, why ?

Comment: Well, my idea was to create model classes like the ones that the LINQ to SQL designer generates.<br/>
For each reference to another table it generates a property which contains the id that points to the primery key of this table and other property which contains the entity itself.<br/>

Comment: Nhibernate doesn't work like that. Just use properties that point to other entities and NH will take care of the rest for you.